# Can't erase cache using fastboot on OnePlus2

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, cache, oneplus-two

My OnePlus2 (I think using OxygenOS) **displays start icons** (normal logo and fastboot, depending on how I boot it), however, afterwards the screen ***always* remains black**, while the phone responds to key presses.

Booting in recovery mode starts up the phone too, but never displays anything.

I tried to clear the cache using `fastboot` (following the [fastboot-info](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) on here), but get this response:

```
$ fastboot erase cache
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this ext4 partition?
erasing 'cache'...
FAILED (remote: device is locked. Cannot erase)
finished. total time: 0.020s
```

When I tried to unlock, following the `-help` suggestions, e.g.:

```
  flashing unlock                          Unlocks the device. Allows flashing
                                           any partition except
                                           bootloader-related partitions.
```

But it doesn't work:

```
$ fastboot flashing unlock
...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.006s
```

And another command I read about seems disabled:

```
$ fastboot oem unlock
...
FAILED (remote: oem unlock is disabled)
finished. total time: 0.009s
```

Is there another way I can erase the cache using `fastboot` or `adb`? I hope clearing the cache might resolve the black screen issue on my phone.

Comment: Black screen in recovery too, doesn't seem to be `/cache` related. Anyway: ***On your phone go to Settings > Developer options. Then enable the 'OEM Unlocking' option.***: https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/24-06-2016-oneplus-2-how-to-unlock-bootloader-flash-twrp-root-nandroid-efs-backup-and-more.345478/. A little bit search is usually helpful.

Comment: Hei, thanks for your comment @IrfanLatif - do you have an idea what else it could be related to if it's not the cache? I've found multiple resources online that mentioned that black screen on startup might get resolved with clearing the user cache, so that's why I've been trying to do that.

Comment: Might be the `/cache` is responsible. But device should boot in recovery mode at least.